# How to get rid of hundreds of PHP undefined index notices?

Tags: php

I just enabled error reporting and wow what a shocker I have probably thousands if not hundreds of notices like this

```
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\webserver\htdocs\header.inc.php on line 18
```

I understand that they are because I am calling a variable withoutsetting it or whatever but is there an easier way to set for example if a page has 50 variables that it is reporting this, is there an easier way to code that page properly to fix them all?

And I don't mean to just hide them I think it would be best to fix them

here is an example of that line I posted

```
if ($_GET['p'] == "account.edit.topfriends" || $_GET['action'] == "newmember" || $_GET['p'] == "account.profile.name") {
    //some more code here
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I usually like to use [ternary](http://www.php.net/ternary) statements at the top of my scripts to initialise values.

```
$_GET['p'] = (isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'default');
```

Sure you could probably use a more generic approach but that method can prove troublesome as different variables can have different default values.

Comment: I actually use this for paging $page = (!empty($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 0; and the error is gone when I am on a page but if no page is set, I get the index error

Comment: What an opportunity to use the new shortened ?: operator from PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 7):

As rezzif mentioned what you need to do is check with an isset() call. If you're using arrays a lot and don't want to go back and add a bunch of isset() calls you can always us a function. Something like:

```
function get_index($array, $index) {
  return isset($array[$index]) ? $array[$index] : null;
}
```

Then you could change your if-statement to something like:

```
if (get_index($_GET, 'p') == "account.edit.topfriends" || get_index($_GET, 'action') == "newmember" || get_index($_GET, 'p') == "account.profile.name") {
  //some more code here
}
```

If all the checks being done are against `$_GET` you could always nix the first parameter of the function and hardcode $_GET in it, my example assumes you're doing this against several different arrays.

This solution isn't necessarily the most elegant, but it should get the job done.

Comment: +1 i like this answer. Gives him the option to do it accross the board. One addition might be to add an optional parameter for a default value.

function get_index($array, $index, $default=null) {
  return isset($array[$index]) ? $array[$index] : $default;
}

Answer (score 0):

Check array elements first using isset() or empty().

E.g,

```
if ((!empty($_GET['p'] && $_GET['p'] == "account.edit.topfriends") || 
    (!empty($_GET['action'] && $_GET['action'] == "newmember")) {
    //some more code here
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using isset given that empty will be true if the value is 0 and he asked how to stop the undefined warnings.

Comment: also, you're missing a closing paren.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of GET and POST undefined index notice(s) forever! Put this in the top of your document...

```
<?php
// Get rid of GET and POST undefined index notice forever! Put this in the top of your document...
class InputData {
     function get($p) {
          return isset($_GET[$p]) ? $_GET[$p] : null;
     }

     function post($p) {
          return isset($_POST[$p]) ? $_POST[$p] : null;
     }

     function get_post($p) {
          return $this->get($p) ? $this->get($p) : $this->post($p);
     }
}
$input = new InputData;

$page = $input->get('p'); // Look in $_GET
$page = $input->post('p'); // Look in $_POST
$page = $input->get_post('p'); // Look in both $_GET and $_POST
?>
```