# Undefined INDEXES when logged out on members page

Tags: php

I have a few £Undefined Indexes when logged out on my members page which I'd like to be viewable for non registered users, or users who stumble across that page.

Notice: Undefined variable: userblock in /home/fights7/public_html/rawfeeds.co.uk/members.php on line 28

```
if($userblock==0) { }
```

AND

Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/fights7/public_html/rawfeeds.co.uk/members.php on line 31

```
if($user2_id==$_SESSION['id']){ }
```

I know you can use ISSET, but don't know where to place it in or around these to make them work like they're suppose to.

MEMBER.PHP

```
<?php
require_once"header.php";
require_once"include/load.php";

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
}
if(isset($data['id'])){
$user2_id=$data['id'];
}
if(isset($user2_id,$user1_id)){
$userblock = user_core::check_block($user2_id, $user1_id);
}
switch($userblock){
case "1":
echo'<div class="userinfo"><hr>You Are Blocked From Viewing This Users Profile<hr></div>';
break;
}
?>   
<?
$Members = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY id");
$numRowsMembers = mysqli_num_rows($Members);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Members)){

$members=user_core::getuser($row['id']);  

if($userblock==0){
$user1_id=(isset($_SESSION['id']));
$user2_id=$row['id'];

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && $user2_id==$_SESSION['id']){
echo '';
}else{
echo'<div class="userinfo"><table border="0"><tr><td>';
echo '<img border=\'0\' src=\'imgs/cropped'.$user2_id.'.jpg\' onerror="this.src=\'img/no_profile_img.jpeg\'" width=\'40\' ><a href="profile.php?username=' .$row['username'] . '">' . $members['fullusersname'] .'</a></tr></td></table>';

?>
<?
$trimmed = trim($row['lives']);
if(!empty($row['lives']))
echo "<b>Lives In:</b> ".$row['lives'];
echo'</div>';
?>
&nbsp;
<?
$trimmed = trim(isset($data['work']));
if(!empty($data['work']))
 echo "<b>Works at:</b> ".$data['work'];
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Would like to know why someone has downvoted the reasonable question. I'm familiar with Isset. But its not just a simple if(isset($variable['id'])){}. Hence the question.

Comment: Honest question: Do you use indentation in your real code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid of hundreds of PHP undefined index notices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242184/how-to-get-rid-of-hundreds-of-php-undefined-index-notices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(isset($userblock) && $userblock==0) { }

if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && $user2_id==$_SESSION['id']){ }
```

Comment: For brevity, the first line can be: `if(isset($userblock) && !$userblock)`

Comment: The _SESSION works fine, but the userblock makes the page dissapear.

Comment: The disappearance of page is due to the logic/error in the rest of your code. Can't help based on the question's info.

Comment: @Yan I've updated the question with the members page. Its short so shouldn't be much to look at. Hope you can help. Thank you.

Comment: You need to use two seperate isset functions to check two different variables: `if(isset($user2_id) && isset($user1_id))`